# loading ELF file into base address diffrent than 0x0

Tags: elf

I want to change my $(LD) command that my ELF file will be loaded from address 0x1000 and not 0x0.
I want to set my first page in my user page table to be inaccesible so the user would not have the ability to access virtual addresses strt from 0x0 to 0x1000
thank you...

Comment: Without knowing more about your platform, and the loader you use, it's impossible to answer your question.